# Populate additional string in append with class using json object mapper

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper, jackson-databind

I have a pojo class like these

```
public class SampleTest {


private transactable tt;

public transactable getTt() {
    return tt;
}

public void setTt(transactable tt) {
    this.tt = tt;
}
```

}

```
public class transactable {


private String transactable;
private String value;
private String departmentid;

public String getTransactable() {
    return transactable;
}

public void setTransactable(String transactable) {
    this.transactable = transactable;
}

public String getDepartmentid() {
    return departmentid;
}

public void setDepartmentid(String departmentid) {
    this.departmentid = departmentid;
}

public String getValue() {
    return value;
}

public void setValue(String value) {
    this.value = value;
}
```

}

Main class is given below Note : Please refer the jars that I am using

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TestString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestString test = new TestString();
        test.substring();
    }

    private void substring() {
        List<String> test = new ArrayList<>();
        test.add("test:111111");
        test.add("test:1122222");

        List<SampleTest> sss = new ArrayList<>();
        SampleTest s1 = new SampleTest();
        transactable t1 = new transactable();
        t1.setTransactable("transactable1");
        t1.setValue("true1");
        t1.setDepartmentid("1111");
        s1.setTt(t1);
        sss.add(s1);
        SampleTest s2 = new SampleTest();
        transactable t2 = new transactable();
        t2.setTransactable("transactable2");
        t2.setValue("true2");
        t2.setDepartmentid("2222");
        s2.setTt(t2);
        sss.add(s2);

        final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);
        String s = null;
        try {
            s = objectMapper.writeValueAsString((sss));
            System.out.println(s);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}
```

The output of the above class is

```
[{"tt":{"transactable":"transactable1","value":"true1"}},{"tt":{"transactable":"transactable2","value":"true2"}}]
```

Expected Results is :

```
[{"tt_4300":{"transactable":"transactable1","value":"true1"}},{"tt_5600":{"transactable":"transactable2","value":"true2"}}]
```

The parent object "tt" needs to be appended with additional string example "4300" ,"5600" .
Please advise how can I do this.

Appreciate your help on this.

Comment: do you have only these two names?

Comment: These two values "4300" ,"5600" are not provided anywhere. You can use `Map<String, Transactable>` instead of `SampleTest` class and create new key as you want.

Comment: Hi Aman, No it will contain N number object like  tt_xxxx, something like this .

Comment: @MichałZiober Thanks for the suggestions,will try that out and yes "4300" ,"5600" i can introduce a field named "departmantid" inside the transactable class and inject that value into that class but how can i form tt_xxxx ? Hope my question make sense.

Comment: @techy360, please update a question with new field

Comment: @MichałZiober It's updated now.Kindly let me know.Btw the solution that you gave to use "Map<String, Transactable>" has worked fine.But I am curious to get answers based on the data population using constructors or by other means.